# Keras Sequential prediction always returning the same result

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, image-classification

This is an algorithm that I used to classify the class of a picture - running shoes, pencil and book. However, after running the algorithm on 3000 ***shuffled*** images (that's all I have), I notice:

1. **val_accuracy for every one of the epochs is the same, equaling 0.3400**
2. **When I print the result from the prediction of 6 images that I took myself, the result array is the following when it's supposed to return a numerical value:**

   `[[1.][1.][1.][1.][1.][1.]]`
3. Since it is always 1, it will always predict the same class for every one of my image, in my case, book.
4. I've conducted a test like another post suggested, to train with 1000 samples each of running shoes and pencils and 1 sample of book. The result is still book, always.

Algorithm:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), input_shape = X_train.shape[1:]))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Conv2D(64,3,3))
model.add(Activation("relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,2)))

model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64))

model.add(Dense(1))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))

model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy",
             optimizer="adam",
             metrics=['accuracy'])

model.fit(X_train, y_train, batch_size=24, epochs=3, validation_split=0.1)

predictions = model.predict(X_test)
```

Output (2692 samples because some are errors)

```
Train on 2692 samples, validate on 300 samples
Epoch 1/3
2692/2692 [==============================] - 17s 6ms/sample - loss: -0.0171 - accuracy: 0.3354 - val_loss: -0.5111 - val_accuracy: 0.3400
Epoch 2/3
2692/2692 [==============================] - 20s 8ms/sample - loss: -0.0171 - accuracy: 0.3354 - val_loss: -0.5111 - val_accuracy: 0.3400
Epoch 3/3
2692/2692 [==============================] - 21s 8ms/sample - loss: -0.0171 - accuracy: 0.3354 - val_loss: -0.5111 - val_accuracy: 0.3400
```

When I run print(predictions), the result is:
`[[1.][1.][1.][1.][1.][1.]]`

Thank you!

Comment: Softmax outputs sum up to 1 and you are using it with one neuron so the result is not suprising at all.

Comment: I'm new to keras, how should I fix the code so that it can describe the possibilities for 3 different classes?

Comment: Change last layer to `model.add(Dense(3))`

Comment: It gives me an error saying 
ValueError: A target array with shape (2992, 1) was passed for an output of shape (None, 3) while using as loss `binary_crossentropy`. This loss expects targets to have the same shape as the output.

Comment: Ah, also loss should be `categorical_crossentropy` if your labels are one hot encoded otherwise `sparse_categorial_crossentropy`.

Comment: Thank you, it works great now! I just realized it makes no sense to use binary if there more than two classes

Comment: Unless you are not doing multi-label classification :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are trying to classify the data into 3 classes the top layer of your model should be

```
model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('softmax'))
```

You do not show the code for how you generated X-train and y_train. If y_train is one hot encoded then you code for model.compile should be

```
model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam",
                   metrics=['accuracy'])
```

if y_train are integers the model.compile should be

```
model.compile(loss="sparse_categorial_crossentropy", optimizer="adam",
                   metrics=['accuracy'])
```